# iconv on cygwin saves the accents

Tags: cygwin

Anyone knows why [iconv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) saves the accents on cygwin? And if so how can I tell it not to.

```
[Nifle@cygwin ~]$ echo "ÅÄÖÕŨÉÁ" | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT
A"A"O~O~U'E'A
```

I want it to behave as it does on my linux servers

```
[NIfle@linux ~]$ echo "ÅÄÖÕŨÉÁ" | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT
AAOOUEA
```

Comment: As a workaround you may want to pipe it through some perl magic: `echo "ÅÄÖÕŨÉÁ" | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT | perl -ne 'foreach (split //) { print "$_" if /\w/; } print "\n";'` which suppresses all non-word characters (`\w`).

Comment: That wouldn't work because the OP might try to parse something containing the string `"Hello"` which would be mistakenly converted to `Hello`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

old issue:

read Kobylkin's comments on this thread...

https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2872#c2

also

http://www.yqcomputer.com/422_10096_1.htm

Remember Cygwin < 1.7 does not have locales.

But **in your case the local seems to be well interpreted**; it is the iconv `Transliteration` process on Cygwin the one that decides to convert a single character into 2 (or even more) components instead of one; in your example you get the transliterated character itself plus the transliterated character modifier (accent, dieresis, tilde, dot, etc.) if present.

```
Å   Ä   Ö   Õ   Ũ   É   Á
A  "A  "O  ~O  ~U  'E  'A

Transliteration:
When a character cannot be represented in the target character set, 
it can be approximated through one or several similarly looking characters
(https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/)
```

you can see the `libiconv.dll` [translit.def](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv/blob/master/deps/libiconv/lib/translit.def) showing the source of the transliteration table (translit.h) created during the "make" process. That table shows that what Cygwin does is in fact correct.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion tables which Cygwin's implementation of iconv uses are different from those on your Linux server.

If you change the locale for Cygwin to the locale of the linux server, you should get the same conversion result.

Answer (score -1):

Cygwin might not be using UTF-8 so is attempting to display
one two-byte UTF-8 character as two one-byte ASCII characters.

Do the following:

1. Go to the **menu** (if you don't see any menu, right click on your Terminal).
2. Click **Options...**.
3. Click **Text**.
4. Set **Locale** and **Character set**

As I don't have Cygwin installed, I cannot tell what the right values are.

See also the Cygwin article [Internationalization - Setup locale](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-locale.html).

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why?